# Updating kitchen electric with GFI

Tags: electrical, kitchens

I need to install two GFI outlets for outlets above countertop but third outlet is for microwave and does not need to be GFI protected. How should this be wired?

Comment: Wire the GFI outlets per the instructions to protect only that one outlet, not any downstream ones. Then each is their own GFI only/

Answer (score 1):

If a GFI outlet is wired with hot and neutral to only the **Line** side, only that outlet has the GFI protection.

If the Microwave is built in it should have its' own dedicated circuit.  If it is a counter model it still needs a GFI outlet. If someone should plug in something else, they would not be protected.

Comment: Yeah exactly, red flag here, a built-in microwave is not allowed on the general-use receptacle circuits.  Gas range and clock only.  And refrigerator, but that's not a good idea.